# Auto click to dynamically added link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to auto click to the dynamically added link. Here is my script

```
document.write("<a id='tikla' href='http://www.example.org'>tikla</a>");

$('#tikla').click();
```

However it doesn't work, because of the link is dynamically added object. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? It looks like you just want to go to the href location?

If that's the case you can just go

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.org';
```

Comment: lol really ? I want to do that in that way, that's why asked it for.

Comment: Okay, well you could use [Mutation Event Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) to determine when your DOM has changed.

Note that the .click function isn't actually supposed to work on a tags, as javascript doesn't really like "fake clicks". So support for that might be removed soon if it isn't already

Answer (score 2):

You need to add click handler before you trigger click event

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ox92gme2/)

```
document.write("<a id='tikla' href='http://www.example.org'>tikla</a>");

$('#tikla').click(function(){
     alert("clicked");
});

$('#tikla').click();
```

For binding events for elements added dynamcially jQuery provides [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

[Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

```
$( "#staticparent" ).on( "click", "#tikla", function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#tikla').get(0).click();
```

Because, you need to emulate the dom element click.

`$('#tikla').click();` will trigger the jquery click event binded to that anchor element. In your case there is nothing binded to the anchor element.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/77/)

Comment: @user198989 see the fiddle

Comment: Thanks but as i said, I am looking for auto click.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this also...

```js
document.write("<a id='tikla' href='http://www.example.org'>tikla</a>");

window.location.href = $('#tikla').attr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("<a id='tikla' href='http://www.example.org'>tikla</a>")
    .appendTo('body') // appendto body
    .get(0).click(); // triggering click to itself
```

```js
$("<a id='tikla' href='http://www.example.org'>tikla</a>")
   .appendTo('body')
   .get(0).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myLink = document.getElementById('tikla');
myLink.click();
```

Thanks for all you guys, but none worked in Internet Explorer. I found this simple javascript works in all of the browsers.